# Can't seem to get bundler working with rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, gem-bundler

I am on rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7

I keep trying to run the bundler command and it doesn't seem to work anymore.

I keep getting

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the trace when running bundler install

```
  /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:11:in `[]': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:215:in `install'
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:325:in `package'
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:13
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/bundle:19
```

Here is what happens when I try to start the server.

```
    /Users/sgedeveloper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:11:in `[]': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/sgedeveloper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:261:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
        from /Users/sgedeveloper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:82:in `configure'
        from /Users/sgedeveloper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
        from /Users/sgedeveloper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `load'
        from /Users/sgedeveloper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
        from ./script/../config/../config/preinitializer.rb:23
        from ./script/../config/boot.rb:29:in `load'
        from ./script/../config/boot.rb:29:in `preinitialize'
        from ./script/../config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
        from ./script/../config/boot.rb:118
        from ./script/server:2:in `require'
        from ./script/server:2
```

Here is Preinitialize.rb

```
    begin
      require "rubygems"
      require "bundler"
    rescue LoadError
      raise "Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with `gem install bundler`."
    end

    begin
      gem 'i18n', "~> 0.4.0"
    rescue LoadError
      raise 'Could not find i18n Gem'
    end


    if Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION) <= Gem::Version.new("0.9.24")
      raise RuntimeError, "Your bundler version is too old for Rails 2.3." +
       "Run `gem install bundler` to upgrade."
    end

    begin
      # Set up load paths for all bundled gems
      ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.expand_path("../../Gemfile", __FILE__)
      Bundler.setup
    rescue Bundler::GemNotFound
      raise RuntimeError, "Bundler couldn't find some gems." +
        "Did you run `bundle install`?"
    end
```

Here is boot.rb

```
  # Don't change this file!
  # Configure your app in config/environment.rb and config/environments/*.rb
  require 'thread'

  RAILS_ROOT = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/.." unless defined?(RAILS_ROOT)

  module Rails
    class << self
      def boot!
        unless booted?
          preinitialize
          pick_boot.run
        end
      end

      def booted?
        defined? Rails::Initializer
      end

      def pick_boot
        (vendor_rails? ? VendorBoot : GemBoot).new
      end

      def vendor_rails?
        File.exist?("#{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/rails")
      end

      def preinitialize
        load(preinitializer_path) if File.exist?(preinitializer_path)
      end

      def preinitializer_path
        "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/preinitializer.rb"
      end
    end

    class Boot
      def run
        load_initializer

        Rails::Initializer.class_eval do
          def load_gems
            @bundler_loaded ||= Bundler.require :default, Rails.env
          end
        end

        Rails::Initializer.run(:set_load_path)
      end
    end

    class VendorBoot < Boot
      def load_initializer
        require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer"
        Rails::Initializer.run(:install_gem_spec_stubs)
        Rails::GemDependency.add_frozen_gem_path
      end
    end

    class GemBoot < Boot
      def load_initializer
        self.class.load_rubygems
        load_rails_gem
        require 'initializer'
      end

      def load_rails_gem
        if version = self.class.gem_version
          gem 'rails', version
        else
          gem 'rails'
        end
      rescue Gem::LoadError => load_error
        $stderr.puts %(Missing the Rails #{version} gem. Please `gem install -v=#{version} rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.)
        exit 1
      end

      class << self
        def rubygems_version
          Gem::RubyGemsVersion rescue nil
        end

        def gem_version
          if defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
            RAILS_GEM_VERSION
          elsif ENV.include?('RAILS_GEM_VERSION')
            ENV['RAILS_GEM_VERSION']
          else
            parse_gem_version(read_environment_rb)
          end
        end

        def load_rubygems
          require 'rubygems'
          min_version = '1.3.1'
          unless rubygems_version >= min_version
            $stderr.puts %Q(Rails requires RubyGems >= #{min_version} (you have #{rubygems_version}). Please `gem update --system` and try again.)
            exit 1
          end

        rescue LoadError
          $stderr.puts %Q(Rails requires RubyGems >= #{min_version}. Please install RubyGems and try again: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org)
          exit 1
        end

        def parse_gem_version(text)
          $1 if text =~ /^[^#]*RAILS_GEM_VERSION\s*=\s*["']([!~<>=]*\s*[\d.]+)["']/
        end

        private
          def read_environment_rb
            File.read("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/environment.rb")
          end
      end
    end
  end

  # All that for this:
  Rails.boot!
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to your Gemfile? What bundler command are you running?

Comment: No changes made to my Gemfile but my Gemfile.lock got deleted.

Comment: got deleted? Are you not using version control?!?!?

Comment: Do you have a `.bundle/config` file or similar in your repo? If so, what are the contents?

Comment: @BrandonTilley That was the issue i figured out. Modified the .bundle/config is what caused this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified the .bundle/config file is what caused this error.

Comment: Wao. Thanks. Indeed, modifying the .config caused the problem to me.